# Apps Script Service Account Ownership Issue

Tags: google-apps-script, service-accounts, google-drive-shared-drive

I encounter the following problem:
An external app is using a service account to copy Google Sheets from a template folder to a shared drive.
After the copy the apps script that is in the Google Sheet is still owned by the service account and can't be run be anyone else.
When a user copies the file once more, the script can be run by the user.
So why is the ownership of the script still the service account while the Google Sheet resides on a shared drive and the shared drive is the owner of the GS?

How can we transfer ownership of the script (not the GS) to the shared drive? or is there another solution?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. How do you know that the script is still owned by the service account? If there is an error message add it textually. P.S. This might be something to be reported to Google Workspace support / Google Apps Script tracker.

Comment: Possible related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70367955/1595451