# How to run an OnEdit function to other sheets with Libraries

Tags: javascript, function, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 8 different Sheets with the same format and i have to run one OnEdit script in each and every one of them

I also dont want the users to Edit the script because of sensitive data

I created a new appscript project from google drive pasted my script there and individually went to all other sheets and added the Library

Do i have to call for that on edit in script or am i missing something

Thank you for the help

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, I guessed your expected result is as follows.

- You have 8 Google Spreadsheets.
- You have a function with the OnEdit trigger. This function can be used for all Spreadsheets.
- You want to use this function for 8 Google Spreadsheets. Also, you don't want to show the script.

In this case, how about using the installable OnEdit trigger? The installable trigger can be also installed by a Google Apps Script project different from the target Google Apps Script project. So, I guessed that when the installable OnEdit trigger is used, your goal might be able to be achieved. The references are as follows.

- My answer: [Creating an onEdit trigger on a sheet owned by a service account](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70373294)
- My blog: [Using OnEdit Trigger to Google Spreadsheet by Hiding Google Apps Script from Other Users](https://tanaikech.github.io/2023/01/25/using-onedit-trigger-to-google-spreadsheet-by-hiding-google-apps-script-from-other-users/)

When this is used, the usage is as follows.

#### 1. Prepare Google Apps Script project.

From `I created a new appscript project from google drive pasted my script there`, I guessed that you already had a Google Apps Script project. You can use this project.

#### 2. Sample script.

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of the Google Apps Script project. And, please set the 8 Spreadsheet IDs of your Spreadsheets to `spreadsheetIds`. And, please set your OnEdit script to the function `installedOnEdit`. Please be careful about the variable name of the event object.

```js
// This function is used as the OnEdit trigger.
function installedOnEdit(e) {

  // Please set your script of OnEdit.

}

function sample() {
  const spreadsheetIds = ["### spreadsheetId 1 ###", "### spreadsheetId 2 ###", "### spreadsheetId 3 ###",,, ];
  const functionName = "installedOnEdit";

  spreadsheetIds.forEach(id => {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
    ScriptApp.newTrigger(functionName).forSpreadsheet(ss).onEdit().create();
  });
}
```

- When `sample` function is run, the function `installedOnEdit` is installed to the 8 Spreadsheets as the installable OnEdit trigger. And, for example, when one of the Spreadsheets is edited, the function `installedOnEdit` is automatically run.

#### Note:

- For example, when you wanted to use the OnEdit script for only one Google Spreadsheet, please set the Spreadsheet ID to `spreadsheetIds` like `const spreadsheetIds = ["### spreadsheetId 1 ###"];`.
- In this case, it supposes that your script of OnEdit works fine and you have permission to use 8 Google Spreadsheets. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [newTrigger(functionName)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#newTrigger(String))
- [Class TriggerBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger-builder)